# Listen to changes after add/update to database angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, nebular

i'm actually listening to the api using this code in my component

```
constructor(){
this.userService.listen().subscribe(
      (m: any) => {
        this.getCurrentMateriDetail();
        }
      }
    )
}
getCurrentMateriDetail() {
    return this.userService.getAdminMateriDetail(this.slug).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.getMateri = data;
        this.currentMateri = this.getMateri.data;
        this.editMateri.patchValue(this.currentMateri);
        this.getCurrentPemateri(this.pemateriCode);
        this.materiSlug = this.currentMateri.slug;
        this.getCurrentMateriLesson(this.materiSlug);
      },
      error => {
        // console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

what i actually want to listen is called LESSON, this lesson is inside TOPIC object, everytime i added new topic it appears on the list immediately. But not with lesson, when i added new lesson, that lesson i've just created not appear on the list. Here's what it looks like

[image]

after i saved it

[image]

my new LESSON is not on the list, if i refresh the page that lesson appear. Idk why in my TOPIC it's working just fine, but not in my LESSON.

here's the response after i added new topic

[image]

my service gives me new data after i hit save, but not on my LESSON, does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it, actually it needs to subscribe again after the dialog closed, so i added this code `this.getCurrentMateriLesson(this.materiSlug);` inside my open dialog function